# Does < form > break height:100%?

Tags: html, css, forms

Simplest of pages to demonstrate my problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body
            {
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            body
            {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #container
            {
                background: red;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

div-container correctly fills the browser window with red. Now wrap the div in a form:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <div id="container"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

and div-container collapses. Why? What is it about a form tag that 'breaks' the 'closest ancester with height'?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`form` is a `block` element, block elements don't have any height unless their content expands or they're explicitly given a height. The closest ancestor of `#container` is `form`, and it's height is `0`, so  `#container`s height is `0`.

Comment: To be perfectly explicit, [`form` is "flow content"](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-form-element.html#the-form-element), browsers will use `display: block` by default.

Answer (score 7):

100% height depends on all ancestors having explicitly declared height. Add a height to the `FORM` and your example should work.

```
HTML, BODY, FORM {
    height: 100%;
}
```

The same holds true for any percentage-based value. If a parent element does not have a height specified its box will be sized based on content. Thus, the child's percentage height will be based on whatever height was calculated for its parent.

Answer (score 2):

try,

```
<style type="text/css">
        html, body, form
        {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
```

or

```
<div id="container">&nbsp;</div>
```

to identify html behave

Answer (score 2):

Just

```
form {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```